# SAML Azure AD SSO Authentication and AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

Followed this article [Azure AD SSO AWS Cognito](https://medium.com/@zippicoder/setup-aws-cognito-user-pool-with-an-azure-ad-identity-provider-to-perform-single-sign-on-sso-7ff5aa36fc2a), created user pool in AWS Cognito and Enterprise application in Azure.

Clicked 'Test single sign on' in SSO, logged in with the user I have added and I am getting error "*Required String parameter 'RelayState' is not present*" after it redirects to this following url https://domainname.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/error?null. When I logged in with invalid user, received message '*User is not assigned to a role for the application*' which is correct.

Anything I am missing here. Please help.

Comment: Is there any update on this? How did you get around it?

Answer (score -3):

If you did everything right, then you should trigger the login from cognito